# python内でgccのエラーメッセージのリスト化

Tags: python, python3, gcc

gccのエラーメッセージを行ごとのリストに格納するにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？
gccコマンドの対象ファイルはコマンドライン引数から用いたいです。

```
#coding:UTF-8

import subprocess
import sys
args = sys.argv
lines = []

proc=subprocess.Popen(['gcc','Wall','Wextra',args[1]+'.c'].splitlines(),stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

lines = proc.stderr
print(lines)
```

上記のコードを実行すると以下のようなエラーが発生してしまいます

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
proc=subprocess.Popen(['gcc','Wall','Wextra',args[1]+'.c'].splitlines(),stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines'
```

例えば以下のようなエラーが発生した場合

```
undec.c: In function 'main':
undec.c:8:2: error: 'z' undeclared (first use in this function)
  z=30;
  ^
undec.c:8:2: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

次のようにリストに格納したいです．。

```
lines=["undec.c: In function 'main':\n","undec.c:8:2: error: 'z' undeclared (first use in this function)/n","z=30;\n","^\n","undec.c:8:2: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in\n"]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Popenではなくrunを使ってください。
2. gccへの引数にハイフンが足りません。
3. proc.stderrはバイナリ文字列になりますから適宜デコードが必要です。

```
import subprocess
import sys
args = sys.argv
lines = []

proc=subprocess.run(['gcc','-Wall','-Wextra',args[1]+'.c'],stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

lines = proc.stderr.decode('utf-8').splitlines(keepends=True)
print(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.Popen()` を使う場合、with 文(context manager)で以下の様に書くこともできます。

```
import subprocess
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
  print("None arguments.", file=sys.stderr)
  sys.exit(1)

args = sys.argv
with subprocess.Popen([
  'gcc', '-Wall', '-Wextra', args[1] + '.c'
], stderr=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8') as proc:
  lines = proc.stderr.readlines()

print(lines)
```